# Fetch data from Firebase using Redux

Tags: reactjs, firebase, redux

I just started using redux, and I'm trying to fetch some data from Firebase and put it in my store. I did some research into the matter and it looked like to me that this:

```
export const addData = (database) => {
  return dispatch => database.ref.once('value').then((snapshot) => {
    dispatch({
      type: 'STORE_DATA',
      payload: snapshot.val()
    });
  }, (err) => {
    dispatch(
    {type: 'STORE_FAILED'})
  })
}
```

should work, however I am getting an error "Error: Actions must be plain objects. Use custom middleware for async actions" when I call

```
store.dispatch(addData(firebase.database()))
```

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a custom middleware like redux thunk or sagas in order to create an action as a function instead of a plain object.

```
npm i redux-thunk
```

Then import this into the file where your store is located.

```
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
```

And add it as an argument to your applyMiddleware function and applyMiddleware as an argument to your createStore function.

```
const store = createStore(rootReducer, 
applyMiddleware(
    thunk
  )
);
```

This should give you the ability to run your async function inside your action.

Comment: Also, don't forget to restart your dev server after you install your dependency as those changes may not take effect until you do so